# Output shape of Lambda layer won't be applied in Variational Autoencoder

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I am trying to rebuild the LSTM VAE model from [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.6114) paper. Code is available [here](https://github.com/arogers1/VAE_LSTM_Text_Encoding/blob/master/vae_lstm.py). I would like to generate sequences with this model in future. The problem for me is that i get an error which says

> ValueError: Input 0 of layer Repeatvector is incompatible with the
> layer: expected ndim=2, found ndim=3. Full shape received: [None, 95,
> 100]

which makes sense. `z.shape` prints `(None, 95, 100)`. What I don't understand here is that although I give `output_shape=(latent_dim,)` to the Lambda layer, it wont be applied? I also tried the original code  from GitHub, but I recieved the same error. For the LSTM i reshape the input data with

```
data_X = np.reshape(data_X,(data_X.shape[0], 1, data_X.shape[1]))
```

and I get `data_X = (274, 1, 95)` which should be okay. `data_Y.shape` is `(274, 95)`

This is my code so far:

```
batch_size = 32
epoch_num = 10
intermediate_dim = 50
latent_dim = 100
val_split = 0.2
input_dim = len(max(data_X, key=len))
timesteps = len(max(data_X, key=len))
Opt_Adam = Adam(learning_rate=1e-4)


def VaeLstmModel():
    inputs = Input(shape=(timesteps, input_dim,), name='Input')
    h = LSTM(intermediate_dim, return_sequences=True, name='LSTM_1')(inputs)
    z_mean = Dense(latent_dim, name='Dense_z_mean')(h)
    z_log_sigma = Dense(latent_dim, name='Dense_log_sigma')(h)
    
    def sampling(args):
        z_mean, z_log_sigma = args
        epsilon = K.random_normal(shape=(K.shape(z_mean)[0], latent_dim), mean=0., stddev=0.1)
        return z_mean + K.exp(z_log_sigma) * epsilon

    z = Lambda(sampling, name='Lambda', output_shape=(latent_dim,))([z_mean, z_log_sigma])

    # Create encoder
    encoder = Model(inputs, [z_mean, z_log_sigma, z], name='encoder')
    
    # Create decoder
    latent_inputs = RepeatVector(timesteps, name='Repeatvector')(z)
    x = LSTM(intermediate_dim, return_sequences=True, activation='relu', name='LSTM_2')(latent_inputs)
    outputs = Dense(input_dim, activation='sigmoid', name='Dense_output')(x)
    decoder = Model(latent_inputs, outputs, name='decoder')
    
    # instantiate VAE model
    outputs = decoder(encoder(inputs)[2])
    vae = Model(inputs, outputs, name='vae_lstm')
    
    vae.compile(optimizer=Opt_Adam, loss=KLDivergence())

    return vae


model = VaeLstmModel()

history = model.fit(x=data_X, y=data_Y, epochs=epoch_num, validation_split=val_split, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, verbose=1)
```

Comment: set return_sequences=False in h = LSTM(intermediate_dim, return_sequences=False, name='LSTM_1')(inputs)... your Y is also 2D while your network is producing 3D... if your input and your target is 2D, why do u need to use a LSTM VAE?

Comment: then i will recieve an error "ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor Tensor("Input_24:0", shape=(None, 95, 95), dtype=float32) at layer "LSTM_1". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []". I have read about LSTM in combination with VAE being good at generating text so I would like to try this out